# Make Eclipse look like Visual Studio 2010

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

I want to make eclipse look like Visual Studio 2010, so I need to know what colors to set the syntax to.

I know where to go in eclipse to change the syntax highlighting, but I don't know the exact colors to use.

Thanks all.

Comment: Can I assume you've seen the [Visual Studio Theme](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=1288) already?

Comment: No I hadn't, think you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I don't work with VS2010, if you can't change colors there and take a look at the defined colors, you canmake screenshots of VS2010 and take a colorpicker.

But again:
Why?

Answer (score 0):

While you wait for answers you could start determine the colors yourself. [Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=color%20picker%20windows) came up with some tools to help you.